# U-SQL get last 3 letters of a string

Tags: c#, string, u-sql

How do I get the last 3 letters of a string using U-SQL? Normally, in SQL I use `RIGHT(MyText, 3)`. In U-SQL that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the C# equivalents, which don't actually include an analogue for a SQL `right`.  Consequently you need to use `Substring`, which naively looks like this:

```
MyText.Substring(MyText.Length-3)
```

This starts the substring at the number of characters in the first argument and, if no second argument is provided, continues to the end of the string.

Being C# however, everything is a little less user friendly than SQL and will error out if your string is less than 3 characters long, as a string that is only 2 characters long will result in a start index of `2 - 3 = -1`, which is not allowed.  So a slightly more robust solution would be:

```
MyText.Length < 3
  ? MyText
  : MyText.Substring(MyText.Length-3)
```

That returns the entire string when it is shorter than 3 characters.  This too will have problems though, if your strings can hold `null` values.  So to be even more robust we can add a `??` check, which is the equivalent of a SQL `isnull()`:

```
(MyText ?? String.Empty).Length < 3
  ? MyText
  : MyText.Substring(MyText.Length-3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your very clear explanation iamdave! It worked for me! Do you also by any chance know how I can specify in my example **{\"pears\":200,\"lemons\":300,\"oranges\":400}"** that I want to extract value (in my example it's **200**) between **"{\"pears\":** and **,\"lemons\"**. Your help is very appreciated!

Comment: Is your source file JSON or just that small bit?  If just that one field and you only ever want to extract the value associated with `pears` you can use a Regex such as `Regex.Match(MyText, @"\\""pears\\"":\d+").Value.Substring(10)` though this isn't very clean.  If the source file is JSON, you should instead look at using a custom JSON extractor, as in an example [here](https://www.taygan.co/blog/2018/01/06/azure-data-lake-series-working-with-json-part-1).

Comment: It's part of the json **{"Data": {"Products": "{\"pears\":200,\"lemons\":300,\"oranges\":400}"}}**. When I use Regex it gives me an error _Inner exception from user expression: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string_.

Comment: @Julia As your source data is Json, I would recommend using a Json Extractor rather than trying to parse out the data yourself.